# Optimize SELECT statement for mysql database

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb-10.1

I have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Other"
FROM events
JOIN triggers ON events.objectid = triggers.triggerid
WHERE events.name REGEXP "No data from SAM0056(.FTG|.REC|.LEFT|.RIGHT|.BACK), .* offline"
AND events.value = 1 
AND triggers.value = 1;
```

In total I need to execute 32 variants of these query depending on the REGEXP. The part "SAM0056" ranges form "SAM50" to "SAM0082". So the pattern is "No data from SAM00XX(.FTG|.REC|.LEFT|.RIGHT|.BACK), .* offline" where XX ranges from 50 to 82.

I also need to execute these query every 15 seconds. So I have a lot of select statements.

These are the DDL for events and triggers:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `eventid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `source` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `object` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `objectid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `acknowledged` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `severity` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`),
  KEY `events_1` (`source`,`object`,`objectid`,`clock`),
  KEY `events_2` (`source`,`object`,`clock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `triggers` (
  `triggerid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `expression` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `priority` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastchange` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comments` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `error` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `templateid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `state` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `flags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recovery_mode` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `recovery_expression` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `correlation_mode` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `correlation_tag` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `manual_close` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`triggerid`),
  KEY `triggers_1` (`status`),
  KEY `triggers_2` (`value`,`lastchange`),
  KEY `triggers_3` (`templateid`),
  CONSTRAINT `c_triggers_1` FOREIGN KEY (`templateid`) REFERENCES `triggers` (`triggerid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

An explain-statement of the query shows this:

```
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type   | possible_keys      | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | events   | ALL    | NULL               | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                   | 8397 | Using where |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | triggers | eq_ref | PRIMARY,triggers_2 | PRIMARY | 8       | zabbix.events.objectid |    1 | Using where |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+--------------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
```

And an insert-statement into these 2 tables (events and triggers):

```
insert into events (eventid,source,object,objectid,clock,ns,value,name,severity) 
values (4985807,0,0,22281,1585805538,856070799,1,'No data from SAM0106-FTG, FortiGate offline',3)

INSERT INTO triggers (description,expression,recovery_mode,type,url,priority,comments,manual_close,status,correlation_mode,recovery_expression,correlation_tag,templateid,triggerid) 
VALUES ('CPU-Temperature to high','{29157}>35','0','0','','3','','1','0','0','','','22515','22541')
```

So how can I optimize these query?
I use mariadb version 10.1.44 on a Ubuntu version 18.04.4.

Comment: Show DDL of the tables (like CREATE TABLE scripts) and an example of the data (as INSERT INTO scripts). *32 variants of these query depending on the REGEXP.* Does some static and complete list of possible values in the `events.name` column exists? Or maybe there exists some pattern of these values?

Comment: You should make A EXPLAIN of your query and see if the indexes are correct. Of cours that is only additional to Akinas suggestion

Comment: Hello, @Akina, I have updated the question. Should I create an Index on the triggers.triggerId table? And makes it a difference if you join the table on the primary key or the index of the table?

Comment: @jarne Your triggers table already has a PRIMARY key index on triggerid.  No need for redundant indexes.  Change SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Other" to SELECT COUNT(event_id) AS "Other" in your first query.  What you do not have is an index for events.objectid (where objectid is the first column of the index), ADD the index, please and retest your first query with EXPLAIN to see the difference.

Comment: @jarne Are you aware MariaDB 10.1.44 became GA on 2020 01 28?  Many people will not try a version less than 6 months old to avoid the 'find and report' bugs requirement for any version with no significant age in the wild.  This is the URL for the extensive changelog - https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-10144-changelog/

Comment: "execute these query every 15" -- 15 days?  15 seconds?  15 users?

Comment: How often are rows inserted into `events`?  (I am looking for whether the Query cache may be useful.)

Comment: @WilsonHauck - No.  `COUNT(primary_key)` is absolutely no better, nor any different than `COUNT(*)`.  The latter is the common, easy to read pattern to use when you are simply counting rows and don't need to check the column for being non-null.  It does not fetch the entire row because of `*`.  Actually, `COUNT(*)` has the latitude to use any index to do the work.  So, if there are "covering" indexes, it will pick the smallest of them.

Comment: Furthermore, regardless of how you phrase `COUNT(...)` it is counting the result of the `JOIN`.  OK, `COUNT(DISTINCT event_id)` does something special -- but mostly that points out that the action is "explode-implode" and might need to be rephrased to avoid the inflated intermediate table.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - 10.1 went GA years ago.  10.1.44 is just a minor release; it does not "go GA".  Probably most of those fixes were backfilling from 10.2/3/4.

Comment: @RickJames 10.1.0 was GA June 30, 2014.  10.1.44 was Jan, 2020 with more than 60 'backfilling' tasks, each of which is an exposure when merging software 6 years later. Just a word of caution to not be the first one on the bus.  Give the version time to age gracefully and avoid self reporting problems, unless you have time available available.

Comment: @WilsonHauck - "GA" means General Availability, aka "Stable".  There several minor releases of a major version before declaring "GA".  10.1.8 was the first GA version; it was not until Oct, 2015.  Ref:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-101-series/ .  Yes, 60 sounds like a large number, but it is about average for all the 10.1 releases since 10.1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FULLTEXT(name)` and `MATCH(name) AGAINST('+SAM0106' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

That will let you quickly whittle down the list of possible rows.  After that, the `REGEXP` (or whatever) can finish the filtering.

`PRIMARY KEY(triggerid)` is the other index that is useful for that `SELECT`.